# Shiny - Hide absolutePanel based on user input

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny dashboard which has a leaflet map in the main panel and some data on absolutePanel (id="controls"). I have some selectInputs. Based on one of the values of the dropdown/selectinput, I want to *hide the absolutePanel*.

SelectInput details:
Id: selectme
choices: c("--","a","b","c")

I want something like, if(input$selectme=="--", hide(absolutePanel(id-"controls"))

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `conditionalPanel`.
From `?conditionalPanel`:

> Usage
>
> conditionalPanel(condition, ...)
>
> Arguments
>
> condition  A JavaScript expression that will be evaluated repeatedly 
>   to determine whether the panel should be displayed.
>
> ...    Elements to
>   include in the panel.

Comment: Thanks! I was just incorrectly writing the conditional javascript expression.